# What is the threshold to consider a Deviance Explained good enough to determine a generalised additive model is fit?

Tags: gam

I have a list of 40,000 species population abundance time series. I have run a GAM for each of them.
Since I can't examine each of the models' output individually due to time constraints, I am trying to automatize the selection of time series that I will keep for further analysis.

As selection criteria to check a GAM is well fitted, I would like to use:

1. k-index and k-index p-value (part of my code below)

```
if ((k_index >= 1) & (k_index_pval > 0.05))
         # gam model is well-FITTED
```

Other criteria, I would like to use

2. model deviance explained
3. significance of smooth term

However, I do not know which is the "adequate" percentage of deviance explained that is acceptable to consider a model well fit.
Does it make sense to use these criteria to select well fit models?

In the past I used R-squared higher or equal of 0.5 as my only selection criteria. But I read in GAMs R squared does not have the same meaning as in linear regression so I discarded it and use it k-index and the p-value of its test p-value.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't fit one model to the 40,000 time series, using the HGAM approach/ideas? https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson! Thank you for your comment and the link to this interesting paper. The reason why I am running a model for each time series is because I would like to explore the effects of multiple anthropogenic stressors on the populations' abundance in the particular locations where those populations were recorded over time.  I may have to reread the paper you have suggested as I could not tell whether Hierarchical generalized additive models for my purpose would make sense. I am new to GAMs, ecology, and R.

Comment: If a GAM works for a single species a model for all species will also work, all else equal. The only problem will be fitting 40,000 random effects/smooths for the species, but depending on what model you are fitting, `gamm()` or `gamm4::gamm4()` should provide reasonable efficiency if you don't need a fancy `family`.